# Emacs indent, use tab for shell and spaces for c

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to configure emacs so C-files are indented with four spaces and shell scripts with tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook (lambda ()
                                (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
                                (set c-basic-offset 4)))

(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook (lambda () (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))
```

Comment: Kind of worked, thanks! I had to add `(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook (lambda () (setq sh-basic-offset 8 indent-tabs-mode t)))`
And it must be 8! If I set offset to 7 instead of 8, emacs will insert spaces, if I add 9 a tab abd a space will be added.

Comment: Emacs completes with spaces when the amount of space it needs to indent a line modulo `tab-width` is not 0.  You can use variable `tab-width` to control "spaces per tabs".  So you could set this to 4 (original value of sh-basic-offset), for instance.

Comment: Tab, four spaces wide: `(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook (lambda () (setq tab-width 4 sh-basic-offset 4 indent-tabs-mode t)))`