# Make Emacs use tab to indent just like ALT I

Tags: c, unix, emacs

I've tried without success to use the tab key to indent my code just like alt + I.

I've modified my .emacs file with the following code but this isn't working :

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
```

Is it possible to use tab to indent code ?

Comment: `M-i` runs the command `tab-to-tab-stop`.  Are you saying you just want `Tab` to do the same?

Comment: Maybe not use the tab key, but being able to add another keyboard shortcut equivalent to [M-i] would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the comments on the question, it sounds like what you want to do is bind another key to do what <kbd>M-i</kbd> does. In order to do that, first we must find what function <kbd>M-i</kbd> is running.  You can do that by hitting <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>M-i</kbd>.  This uses the function `describe-key` to describe what function the key is bound to.

For me, <kbd>M-i</kbd> maps to the function `tab-to-tab-stop`.  Since you may be in a different mode you may have a different function.

Once you have the function you can easily map that to any key.  In the example below I've mapped it to <kbd>F2</kbd> on the global keymap:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2>") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
```

Different modes also have their own keymaps.  If you wanted to map this key only while in certain modes then you'd first have to determine which keymap was active while in the specific mode.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you also need to add this config under yours:

```
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
```

Good luck with emacs!

Comment: Hey, by adding your line, emacs does indent code but only at the beginning of a new line, if I write something, it does not work anymore.

Comment: Ok, so try with tab-stop then. (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 4 200 4))

Comment: Working perfectly fine except in source files, if I try in a .c file it isn't working but this is exactly what I want when the file has no extension

Comment: There is a C hook that I found on a post : (set c-basic-offset 4) . Here is the post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402822/emacs-indent-use-tab-for-shell-and-spaces-for-c

Comment: Not working either, I guess I'll have to keep on using M + I